# How to plot binary values with pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the score of 100 students that passed two exams. The X value is the First Exam Score and the Y value is the Second Exam Score. I have a third column in my dataframe that is either 0 or 1. If they got admitted to the university with the score they got in the two exams, it is indicated with a 1 in my third column. If they did not get admitted, there is a 0.

I am trying to plot dots when they did not get admitted, and '+' when they got admitted.

How do I do this?

This is the code I have right now:

```
data.plot(kind='scatter', x='First Exam Score', y='Second Exam Score', figsize=(12,8))
```

This is the graph I have right now:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/zOSzFdG]

I want some points to be dots and some others to be '+', depending on the value they have in the third column

Comment: Is it a `pandas` dataframe? Is so, you might add the `pandas` tag. Also, you might want to add a sample of your dataframe (10 - 20 row are enough) so that people can better understand the question and try to help you. Add it as text, not as image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do plot the selected data into the same axis:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'First': np.random.randint(30,100, 100),
                     'Second': np.random.randint(30,100,100),
                     'Admitted': np.random.randint(0,2,100)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
markers = ['x','o']

for i in range(2):
    data[data['Admitted'].eq(i)].plot.scatter(x='First', 
                                              y='Second', 
                                              marker=markers[i],
                                              ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]

Or you can use seaborn `scatterplot` with `style`:

[image]

But in my opinion, a better way is to color code with seaborn:

```
sns.scatterplot(data=data, x='First', y='Second', hue='Admitted', style='Admitted')
```

Output:

[image]